# What's the difference between broccoli from China and broccoli from Australia?

Tags: broccoli

They look pretty similar except the Australia ones cost more than twice the ones from China. Taste-wise, there are only subtle differences according to my tastebuds.

Is there a reason Australia broccoli is more expensive? Is it a nutritional thing, a taste thing, or a supply thing (I supposed they grow more broccoli in China)?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I'm located in Singapore, so that might make a difference :)

Comment: Fresh or frozen? Fresh broccoli degrades very fast

Comment: Are you sure they are the same...? Chinese broccoli is this: http://steamykitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/broccoli-beef-noodles-8.jpg and "Australian" makes me think of this: http://www.dpi.vic.gov.au/__data/assets/image/0007/29761/broccoli.jpg

Comment: I would think it's a supply thing - Australia has relatively limited agricultural resources.

Comment: @Jay Chinese growers also grow traditional western vegetables specially for export

Comment: @ElendilTheTall where did you get that impression? e.g. they are the worlds second largest beef exporter, tenth largest wheat producer, etc. etc. And all from a modest population and water supply

Comment: @Jay, in China people eat broccoli as per your second picture. Your first pic looks more like spinach to me.

Comment: @TFD: [According to the Australian government](http://www.anra.gov.au/topics/agriculture/pubs/national/brassicas.html) Australia produces ~40000 tons broccoli/year. China is the biggest producer in the world, [at 8 million tons/year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broccoli)!

Comment: @nico Last time I check China had a slightly bigger population than Australia :-) Either way it's hardly "limited agricultural resources"

Comment: @Jay Yup that's Chinese broccoli (or we actually prefer to call it Kai-lan), which I'm not referring to. I'm referring to broccoli that looks just like your 2nd picture, but it's labeled as being from China.

Comment: @TFD: surely, I was just pointing out that being the biggest producer in the World, China is able to sell worldwide at a lower price. I remember when living in NZ that kiwi wine was often more expensive than French or Italian wine of similar quality for similar reasons (I assume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that the following things make a vegetable more expensive:

- quantity of supply (if a shop has more product to move in a limited time they make it cheaper)
- quality of supply (eg organic)
- distance to supply (if it costs more to move it from source to destination)
- age of supply (products near expiration are cheaper because the shop needs to sell them)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the growing practices of China compared to Australia.  Unless you are saying Organic then you don't have much regulation of how things are grown.  Very little testing too with exception of the high risk items which get hit with ecoli every so often in California and other parts of the world.

Second is labour cost.  What's the minimum rage in Australia for farm workers and what's it in China?

Third is transportation costs.  Shipping vegetables in container ships without refridgeration means high losses so it might not make financial sense to export via ship so you're left with plane and that's even higher in cost.  Looking at the map...you're half way between Australia and China BUT you have roads and warehouses all the way into China while Australia just has open Ocean.

Comment: It's generally cheaper to ship by ship, than by road

Comment: For non-perishables, yes.